# storing filtering logic in configuration - applying filtering against a DTO

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

**How can we pass in some sort of filtering delegate through configuration?**

I've got a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class Translation
{
    public DateTime DateTime {get;set;}
    public string TranslateTo {get;set;}
    public string TranslateFrom {get;set;}
}
```

I am making use of this DTO within my method

```
public void DoWork(Translation translation)
{
    WriteToDb(translation);
}
```

I would like to be able to apply a filter and NOT execute `WriteToDb`:

```
public void DoWork(Translation translation, TranslationFilter filter)
{
    //apply the filter to translation, and exit this function, otherwise continue:
    WriteToDb(translation);
}
```

I would like this `TranslationFilter` to be something that is configurable through regular JSON.

**How can we apply filtering to the fields of a DTO, while allowing this filtering logic to be configurable through json configuration?**

Comment: did you mean to tag azure-functions? I'm not sure how this is related to azure-functions. Can you elaborate more on that if it was intentional

Comment: @ahmelsayed great question. yes the `azure-functions` tag was indeed deliberate. the reason i tagged it this way is because the configuration on azure functions is much more intricate than regular c# .net apps